# Add To Cart does not work - Redux - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am creating an ecommerce store and using redux to manage the state, I have setup the reducer and even followed a youtube video exactly to make sure it was working perfect as my experience with redux is limited. The code is exactly the same as the video however it does not work the same.

When I add the item to a cart through pressing basket button on the card it updates the UI display at the top to show the cart has an item in it, however it does not add this item to the cart array as it does not show up in the basket - and when looking at Redux dev tools no state changes are detected on that either.

Here is a link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/live/96tz2pe).

Comment: Shouldn't you call the method `mapDispatchToProps` instead of `addToCart` on line 79 inside Card.js? Because `addToCart` exists inside of `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: I get your point, tried that but that doesn't fix it and in fact when I just tried that now and then tried to add to basket it doesn't even update UI of basket in menu at top so would not be a solution. In terms of why the method is called mapDispatchToProps to my best understanding this is best practise for Redux or atleast how I think it is suppose to be done from what i've read and watched online - I could be wrong though!